# Combining distinct and count() from two tables

Tags: sql, count, inner-join, distinct

I have two tables:

```
Customers (name, address, postcode (FK))
Postcodes (postcode (PK), county)
```

I want to find out how many customers are in each county.

I am assuming I need an inner join on postcode but don't know how to combine this with a `count(customer_id)` and `distinct(county)`.

Comment: Look up `group by` in any tutorial or book on SQL. This is very basic SQL - please do some research before asking here.

Comment: I have SQL Server 7.0 programming. however the sections on Group are all related to a single table as are the Count examples I'm struggling on how to use them through an inner join where the distinct statement is in one table and the count in another.

Comment: You don't need to use `distinct` for the kind of query you're doing, you just `group by` that column.  The join should make no difference.

Comment: Look at the sections on `Inner Join` and figure out how to create a single result for both tables.  Then use the section on `Group` to get your count by Postcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you *can* write queries with `SELECT DISTINCT country` it prevents you from doing aggregates such as `COUNT`.  Instead you can use `GROUP BY` which broadly has the same effect as `DISTINCT` but with much more power and flexibility.

These two queries give the same results, but the second lets you then go on to add your `JOIN` and `COUNT` statements.

```
SELECT DISTINCT county FROM postcodes

SELECT county FROM postcodes GROUP BY county
```

By and large, don't use `SELECT DISTINCT`, but use this kind of pattern...

```
SELECT
    postcodes.county,
    COUNT(customers.customer_id)
FROM
    postcodes
INNER JOIN
    customers
        ON customers.postcode = postcodes.postcode
GROUP BY
    postcodes.county
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Looks simple when you know how.

Answer (score 0):

Just join the Customers table to the Postcodes table on the common field 'postcode '.  Then you can use `Group By` to get your counts and return one row per `County`

```
SELECT 
    County,
    COUNT(Customer_Id) CustomerCount
FROM    
    Postcodes pc
    JOIN Customers c ON pc.PostalCode = c.PostalCode
GROUP BY
    County
```